# How to reset the ATG Dynamo Admin password?

Tags: atg

How can I reset the ATG Dynamo Admin password?

I need steps to reset/change the password, from the default of `admin/admin`.

Answer (score 3):

According to Oracle's documentation, you can add **Admin.Reset** to your ear file which when deployed, will reset the admin password to the admin account.

[ATG Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGProgGuide/html/s2301appendixeatgmodules01.html)

Comment: This is the correct and recommended way to achieve this. It also works in ATG 11.x while I've had issues with the database approach suggested below. It is annoying to have to include the module to start with so recommend you don't forget your password.

Answer (score 3):

Delete entry for "admin" from DAS_ACCOUNT table and restart the server. Then open dyn admin with admin/admin. It will take you to passward reset page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this ACC. In ACC click on **People and Organizations->Control center users** and select the name whose password you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

It is answered in [This](https://forums.oracle.com/message/10331032) forum. Basically, there are different ways to reset password, you can do it either by firing some queries or by methods mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. In WebLogic app server I was getting denied ATG Dyn Admin of admin/admin. I took a shot in the dark and tried my WebLogic admin console login, and this time it worked, but Dyn Admin tried to take me to a password reset page. At that time I got the error:

Make sure that you have the `bin` directory for your JDK in your `PATH` variable before starting Dynamo and that you have enough swap space.

I created below props file in `ATG_HOME/localconfig`, and added the one liner below:

```
/atg/dynamo/servlet/pagecompile/ExtendedJhtmlPageProcessor

javaCompilerClassName=atg.servlet.pagecompile.SunJavaSourceCompiler
```

This solved my problem. I was able to load password change JHTML fine. Not sure yet why ATG Dyn Admin was redirecting me to password change page, and why it accepted my WebLogic console credentials. I wonder if it's a WebLogic specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your password through /dyn/admin console there is a link password management from where you can reset the default password from admin/admin

Answer (score 0):

Open your SQL developer in Core schema there is table name DAS_ACCOUNT where account name and password has been set so for password there is a long key

i have a key with me 
2b7b1f41d6ddb810d48096c266d3bd092d7e5da5
place it in there now your 
username:admin
Password:admin123